# Couldn't find Team with ID=2 for Match with ID=

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to do a many to many relations ship.

I have two models, Teams and Matches and i'm doing a many-to-many relations ship but getting this error when trying to save a nested model.

'Couldn't find Team with ID=2 for Match with ID='

I know that my model is new so it doesn't have an id yet, but i'm using the Match.new(params[:match] method which should work.

```
Team:
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :status

  attr_protected :id


  has_many :matchships
  has_many :matches, :through => :matchships


end

Match:
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :date, :name

  attr_protected :id

  has_many :matchships
  has_many :teams , :through => :matchships

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :teams
end


MatchShips:
class Matchship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :match_id, :team_id


  belongs_to :match 
  belongs_to :team 
end


Match Controller:

New:

  def new
    @match = Match.new

    @match.teams.build

  end


Create:

  def create
 'failing here' -------->   @match = Match.new(params[:match])

    @team = Team.find(params[:team_id])
    @match.teams << @team
    @team.matches << @match
```

Form:

```
<%= nested_form_for(@match) do |f| %>
  <% if @match.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@match.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this match from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @match.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :date %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :teams, :html => { :class => 'form-vertical' } do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.label "Team Name:" %>
    <%= builder.autocomplete_field :name, autocomplete_team_name_teams_path, :update_elements => {:id => "##{form_tag_id(builder.object_name, :id)}" },:class => "input-small",:placeholder => "Search" %>
  <%= builder.hidden_field :id %>

  <% end %>

  <%= f.link_to_add raw('<i class="icon-plus-sign"></i>'), :teams, :class => 'btn btn-small btn-primary' %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Controller

Comment: Can you show us the form and controller action with which you are trying to save nested model? Association seems to be correctly configured.

Comment: why do you have attr_protected :id in your models?

Comment: because you would get this: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: teams_attributes